# Creating a line from lots of easting/northing co-ordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, route

I have hundreds of easting northing points which I need to join as a single line to show a route.  How do I import them and get QGIS to automatically turn them into a line?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/workflow-for-creating-line-features-between-two-coordinate-pairs-in-qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import of coordinates from a CSV table can be done with `Add delimited text`.

To create a line from them, use the `Points2One` plugin.

Or use the `MMQGIS` plugin to do both steps together.

Comment: Perfect!  Used mmqgis plugin as suggested.  Thanks very much!