# Why does Points2One complain "Can't make a polyline out of one points."?

Tags: qgis, points-to-line

I am trying to connect pairs of points by lines using the Points2One tool in QGIS. I have created the data and exported it as shapefile. The data looks similar to the data in this question: 
[Workflow for creating line features between two coordinate pairs in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/workflow-for-creating-line-features-between-two-coordinate-pairs-in-qgis)

The problem is after grouping the data by id and sorting by order I get an error which says `"Can't make a polyline out of one points."` I am not sure what I am doing wrong here as I am new to QGIS.

[image]

[image: Error image]

```
Here's the attribute table:
id,       order,    longitude,  latitude
stream1,    1,     80.187006,   12.989196
stream1,    2,     78.509647,   17.441657
stream2,    1,     78.454394,   17.242307
stream2,    2,     80.157087,   13.112136
```

Comment: Can you add the attribute table of the `location`point layer? Are you sure that several points share the same `id` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember this tool having two sorting inputs ... anyway this works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm. I am using QGIS version 2.10.1 maybe that's the reason for two sorting inputs.

Comment: Is there a way to display values on the lines. I want to put a number on each line. Is it possible ? Does QGIS have a tool for that ?