# QGIS: calculate distance between points

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I'm using QGIS 2.8.

I need to calculate the distance between points depending on points ID (not nearest point). I have a CSV table including points ID and coordinates. Each point is referenced on 2 different lines with a different pair of coordinates. I need to know the distance between the 2 positions of each point.

[image]

I have tried fTools plugin but the Distance matrix function returns nearest points measures (I had beforehand splitted the CSV table in 2 sets of unique points ID).

Any idea about a plugin or function that would enable to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the Points2One plugin mentioned in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15909/workflow-for-creating-line-features-between-two-coordinate-pairs-in-qgis).

You should be able to create lines, grouped by the point IDs. Once you have the line layer you could calculate a line length to get the distance between the two points.

FYI - using the plugin on Mac created the line layer but wouldn't add it to my project, I thought it did't work but it does. You just have to load your line layer back into the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this link: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/origin_destination_matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

Open the CSV in Excel or LibreOffice Calc and use the distance formula.
[image]